# How to prove that $(\bar{A})' \subset A'$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I'm trying to prove the following.

> For any $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, $(\bar{A})' \subset A'$.

where $\bar{A} = A \cup A'$ : closure of $A$.

**My attempt**

If $(\bar{A})' = \emptyset$ then trivial. Otherwise, $\forall a \in (\bar{A})'$, $\forall \epsilon > 0$ $\exists b \in \bar{A} $ such that $0 < |b-a| < \epsilon/2$.

(**Case1**) If $b \in A$, since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, we have $a \in A'$.

(**Case2**) If $b \in A' \cap A^{c} $, then $\exists c \in A - \{a\}$ such that $0 < |c - b| < \epsilon/2$. By triangle inequality, we have $0 < |c - a| < \epsilon$, since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, we have $a \in A'$.

Is my proof right? I feel somewhat uncomfortable with the **Cases** part in my proof. It seems, that my proof is alright, only in the following scenario.

Someone gives me $\epsilon>0$. Then every time I always have such $b \in \bar{A}$, but my $b$ can be in **Case 1** or in **Case 2**, depending on $\epsilon$ So in the situation that the fate of $b$ depends on the choice of $\epsilon$, my reasoning does not seem to be held true. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just choose $\varepsilon_n =\frac{1}{n}$ then you have a sequence $b_n$ such that either of the cases hold. This sequence is infinite so at least one of the cases must happen for infinitely many $n$ that is when you approach $a$ arbitarily close.